# Django: set cookie on test client?

Tags: python, django

My Django site is set up with some middleware that on each request, checks for a cookie, and if it is not set, forwards the user elsewhere.

I now want to run some tests on the site. This is my code:

```
def test_contactform(self):
    response = self.client.get('/contact/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    print response
    self.assertTrue('Contact me' in response.content)
```

Unfortunately, this fails with:

```
Vary: Cookie
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://testserver/ldap/?next=/contact/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 43, in test_contactform
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 302 != 200
```

Can I either (i) set a cookie on the Django test client (and if so how) or (ii) require the Django test client to follow the redirect and test against the final page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `client.get` method takes a `follow` argument which allows it to follow redirects:

```
response = self.client.get('/contact/', follow=True)
```

Answer (score 26):

None of the above worked for me (Django1.9, Python3.4). Found this solution [here](http://blog.sneawo.com/blog/2015/03/20/test-django-view-with-cookies/):

```
from django.test import TestCase    
from http.cookies import SimpleCookie


class TestViewWithCookies(TestCase):

    def test_votes(self):
        self.client.cookies = SimpleCookie({'name': 'bla'})
        response = self.client.get('/vote/2')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: to make this work in both py2 and py3 you can just use `from django.http.cookie import SimpleCookie` :)

Answer (score 12):

While the accepted answer is the right approach for this problem, I just want to point out that you *can* set cookies directly (i.e. approach number (i) as you call it), but not via the test client.  Instead you need to use a [`RequestFactory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.RequestFactory) to construct a request which you can set the cookie on, then pass that directly to the view in question.

So instead of:

```
response = self.client.get('/contact/')
```

you do:

```
request = RequestFactory().get('/contact/')
request.COOKIES['thing'] = 'whatever'
response = contact_view(request)
```

where `contact_view` is the view serving `/contact/`.

Comment: What version of django were you using? in 1.7 you can set cookies like this on a request: `self.client.get('xyz',cookies=Cookie.SimpleCookie())`

Comment: *nods* - good point. I was using 1.4 in this case. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: If you're here to `rf.post` bypassing csrf check, this thread https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/957 showed me to use `request._dont_enforce_csrf_checks = True`.

Answer (score 11):

You can set cookies for test client by calling load on `cookies` attribute which is [SimpleCookie](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/http.cookies.html?highlight=simplecookie#http.cookies.SimpleCookie) object.

```
from django.core import signing

self.client.cookies.load({
    'example': '123',
    'signed_example': signing.get_cookie_signer('signed_example').sign('123')
})
```

Django's test client is stateful - will persist cookies between tests and will ignore expire dates. For removal, you need to manually remove cookie or create a new client. - [See docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#persistent-state)

--- For Python 3 and Django 2+

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but maybe this is handy for someone:

```
from http.cookies import SimpleCookie

from django.test import TestCase, Client


class CookieClientTests(TestCase):
    def test_cookie(self):
        cookies = SimpleCookie()
        cookies["cookie_key"] = "something"
        client = Client(HTTP_COOKIE=cookies.output(header='', sep='; '))

        resp = client.get("/")
        self.assertEqual(200, resp.status_code)
```

Comment: This answer uses the Python 3 http.cookies library. In Python 2 use `Cookie`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookie.html