# How to set a cookie in a django test case?

Tags: python, django

I'm struggling to figure this one out, sessions work when i run my application normally but i can't figure out how to set data in the session in my test case.

The docs say in a test case you have to save the session to apply the changes before making the request. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/testing/#persistent-state

e.g.

```
from django.test import TestCase

class TestLogin(TestCase):

    def test_processuser(self):
        redirect = '/processuser/'
        session = self.client.session
        session["id"] = '1234'
        session.save()
        response = self.client.get(redirect)
```

However the session object returned from self.client.session is just a normal python dict?

Diging into the code the Client.session call is this:

```
def _session(self):
    """
    Obtains the current session variables.
    """
    if 'django.contrib.sessions' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
        cookie = self.cookies.get(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME, None)
        if cookie:
            return engine.SessionStore(cookie.value)
    return {}
session = property(_session)
```

`cookie = self.cookies.get(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME, None)` returns `None` so it just returns a dict in stead of a session store.

It looks like i have to do some more preparation in the test client before i save a session? Not really got much experience in this any help would be appreciated.

Django 1.2.5
Python 2.6.5

Cheers,

Asim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to login as someone, so the test client would set the cookie for you.

```
self.client.login(username,password)
```

should do. Refer the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.client.Client.login) for more.

Answer (score 8):

Edit: this answer is now outdated; as of at least Django 1.7, you can just set the cookie directly on the test client.

See e.g. [this answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297668) or [the comments on this answer to another, similar, question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24576524).

Old outdated answer follows...

---

Adding this for people who really **do** need to set a cookie, e.g. because they need to do something which isn't covered by the Django auth mechanism...

You can't set cookies directly on `TestClient` objects but if you use the [`RequestFactory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.RequestFactory) class you can do it.  So instead of (say):

```
response = Client().post('/foo')
```

you do:

```
request = RequestFactory().post('/foo')
request.COOKIES['blah'] = 'hello'
response = foo_view(request)
```

where `foo_view` is the view corresponding to the '/foo' path, i.e. the view you're looking to test.

HTH somebody.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to the most upvoted answer, you **CAN** set cookies directly on the test client.

*Remember everything is an object, you just have to know where/what to patch*

so it goes like this:

```
client.cookies[key] = data
```

`client.cookies` is an instance of `http.cookies.SimpleCookie` from the standard library and it behaves like a `dict`. so you can use `.update` for bulk updates to a cookies value. This can be useful if you want to alter other cookie values like `max-age`, `path` `domain` etc.

Finally, if you want to set a `signed_cookie`, You can reuse the helpers from django like this:

```
from django.core.signing import get_cookie_signer

signed_cookie_value = get_cookie_signer(salt=key).sign(data)
client.cookies[key] = signed_cookie_value
```

Pay attention to the salt. It has to match on both ends (Signing and retrieval). A Different salt value for signing would generate a different cookie that cannot be retrieved when you call `response.get_signed_cookie(key)`

Answer (score 0):

For other people who are running into this problem please be aware that the `Client.logout()` function will throw away your cookies. For example:

```
response = self.client.post(self.url, self.data)
print response.client.cookies.items()  # Displays the cookie you just set

self.client.logout()

response = self.client.post(reverse('loginpage'), {'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'}, follow=True)
print response.client.cookies.items()  # Does not display the cookie you set before since it got destroyed by logout()
```

To make sure your cookies stay alive during testing make a call to your logout page in stead of using the `Client.logout()` function, like so:

```
response = self.client.post(self.url, self.data)
print response.client.cookies.items()  # Displays the cookie you just set

self.client.get(reverse('logoutpage'))

response = self.client.post(reverse('loginpage'), {'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'}, follow=True)
print response.client.cookies.items()  # Does display the cookie you set before since it did not get destroyed by client.logout()
```